# SSO relay state issue

Tags: angularjs, rest, single-sign-on, websphere-liberty, idp

I created angularjs web application which calls REST web service for data. Both web application and rest services running in the same WebSphere liberty container. I am using SSO federation to authenticate users. Here the problem is when session time outs and after that if the user doing some actions. Web application calls rest services and sending back relay state HTML as results instead of expected data. How to fix this by redirecting automatically to SP login URL.

Answer (score 0):

Does your application send any security token to REST service for authentication? I guess that the request is unauthenticated, and rest service is configured as SAML SP, so the REST service sends a login request via client (it happens to be angular web application). Can you explain if your angular application has performed authentication before web service call? Based on the topology described, I would suggest that you set up angular web application to perform OpenId Connect or OAuth login, then sends access_token or JWT to Rest service.

Comment: Yes. The angular application performs initial authentication by redirecting to SP and SP send back response back to our application. During that time we make a lot of rest calls everything goes fine. But after session time out(LTPA), if we make rest call. it replies back with some sort of relay state message as HTML with auto submit form.

Comment: could you share SP's configuration (server.xml) with me?